# How to prove that image and inverse image form a Galois connection

Tags: galois-connections

Let $f'\colon X \to Y$ and $P(X)$ and $P(Y)$ be the powersets of $X$ and $Y$.
Let $f \colon P(X) \to P(Y)$,
   $f(U) = \{ y \in Y | \exists x \in U (f'(x) = y) \},$
and $f^{-1} \colon P(Y) \to P(X)$,
   $f^{-1}(V) = \{ x \in X | \exists y \in V (f'(x) = y) \}.$
Then $(f,f^{-1})$ forms a Galois connection between $P(X)$ and $P(Y)$, when both of these sets are ordered by inclusion.

How to prove (simply) that $f(U) \subseteq V$ if and only if $U \subseteq f^{-1}(V)$?

If we assume that $f(U) \subseteq V$, then $f(U)$ includes elements $y \in Y$ so that $f'(x)=y$ for some $u \in U$  and $V$ includes all of these elements and maybe more. 
But the set $f^{-1}(V)$ includes only the elements $x \in X$ which for $f'(x)=y$ for some $y \in V$.
So obviously $U \subseteq f^{-1}(V)$. But this is kind of a mess, how to prove this in a more simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that $f(U) \subseteq V$.
Then $f^{-1}(f(U)) \subseteq f^{-1}(V)$.
It is known that $U \subseteq f^{-1}(f(U))$, so now $U \subseteq f^{-1}(V)$, because the relation $\subseteq$ is transitive.
Hence, if $f(U) \subseteq V$ then $U \subseteq f^{-1}(V)$.

And same works the other way around, assuming that $f(f^{-1}(V)) \subseteq V$ is known.